# Select multiple areas in a picture

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mootools, crop

I need to achive something like this:

[image: petaca]

As you can see, we have a base picture of a motherboard, and then 2 specifics areas of this pictures highlighted. On the left we have a component image, and the user has to choose one of the hilighted areas.

I checked jQuery JCrop, Mootools Moocrop... but neither one seems to be valid. What I want is to set a base big picture and select 2 or more areas there. I will store the coordenates on the database.

After that, I'll load the picture with the areas and ask the user to choose one area, like in the picture.

Does anyone have any clue how can I achive that?

Comment: Do you want users to click on certain spots, or drag-select entire areas? The first one would be far easier to implement, and would probably be more intuitive for the user as well.

Comment: One way: Slice the picture so that both parts that can be select can be linked with the HTML a tag. A user then can click on a link. You don't need even javascript for that.

Comment: @mblase75 the first way.

Comment: @hakre what I am building is going to be a form builder or something like that. First, a technician will upload a picture and select 2 or more areas in this picture saving all the info into the database. After when a user loads the page, has to choose one of the areas. 
I think that I should build this with javascript storing area coordenates or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2009/01/23/img-notes-v02-a-couple-of-bug-fixes-and-some-more/ may help you with some changes in the JS.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the actual mechanics of the highlighting of the areas, if you want to make those areas clickable or otherwise JS-actionable, you can use an old-school [HTML image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map).

Comment: I know a HTML Image map, but it isn´t usefull for me. I need to spicify some areas in one picture an make them highlighted someway and make them avaible for clicking

Comment: You could use the coordinates in the image map to superimpose an empty bordered div on top of the image (assuming rectangular areas only). That gives you a visible clickable area.